# Is there any way to call multiple methods with one route in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send some data to my admin dashboard page. The data is for two charts: the first displays the number of articles posted by users in the past week and the other displays the last five articles. However, each of these datas are returned from separate methods of my controller.
So far, I have fetched all the data I need from the database in one method and returned a view with all the data, In this way:

```
  return view('admin', compact('lastUserPosts'))->with('week', json_encode($week))
            ->with('postNo', json_encode($postNo));
```

and a normal route like:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
```

clearly I'm not following the single responsibility principle, so I'm wondering How can I write my code to fetch each set of data from its own method in controller and then call both of these methods in one route.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... refactor the code you need to reuse out of the controller, then you can call it from any place you need ... then this single route can call the needed code to get the data without having to call other controller methods

Comment: You can research Laravel Service-Repository pattern. This pattern have design pattern methodologies. If you add a service with this pattern, it has got single responsibility principle You can read this article enter link description here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you watch Laracon EU conference there was a talk titled [becoming a better developer](https://youtu.be/rtmFCcjEgEw) by using the SOLID principles, aside from that what you can do is separate the logic of the contoller from formatting and fetching the data by creating a middle layer between it and the model something like a `PostsRepository` now this class should contain the fetching and ajax formating of the Model, import it in your contoller `use App\Repository\PostsRepository` and instead of the normal model that you enject to your controller method use the Repository instead

```php
Public function getAllPosts( PostsRepository $post) {
    .....
}
```

Now you have access to all the method of the Post model from a different class and you can also test it easily